# Passing object parameters from cshtml view to controller in ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, view, controller

I am trying to pass some object values from MVC view to my controller. But having issues that the values are unable to pass to my controller as it keeps complaining that the values are not passed? Is there anything I need to take note on the formatting of the object types or some encoding settings here?

**Code from controller**

```java
public class saveViewModel
{
  public List<NgpartDetails> ngpartDetails { get; set; }
  public List<GeneralDetails> generalDetails { get; set; }  
}

[HttpPost]
public void MyActionSubmit(saveViewModel viewModel)
{ 

    foreach (var ngpartdetail in viewModel.ngpartDetails)
    {
        NgpartDetails Ng1 = new NgpartDetails { Number = ngpartdetail.Number,
        Quantity = ngpartdetail.Quantity, Reason = ngpartdetail.Reason, Nghandling = ngpartdetail.Nghandling,
        Remarks = ngpartdetail.Remarks };

        efngpartdetails.NgpartDetail.Add(Ng1);
    }

    efngpartdetails.SaveChanges();

}
```

**javascript code**

```js
$("body").on("click", "#buttonSubmit", function () {
    console.log("button submit clicked")

    var generalDetails = [];
    generalDetails.push({
        Date: $("#date").val(),
        LotNo: $("#lotno").val(),
        PartName: $("#partname").val(),
        LotProductionDate: $("#lotproductiondate").val(),
        Number: $("#partno").val(),
        ImportQty:$("#importquantity").val()
    })

    var ngpartDetails = [];

    $("#ngpartdetails TR.data-row").each(function () {
        var row = $(this);
        ngpartDetails.push({
            Number : row.find("TD").eq(0).html(),
            Quantity : row.find("TD").eq(1).html(),
            Reason : row.find("TD").eq(2).html(),
            Nghandling : row.find("TD").eq(3).html(),
            Remarks : row.find("TD").eq(4).html()
        });

    });

    var viewModel = {
        ngpartDetails: ngpartDetails,
        generalDetails: generalDetails
    }


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/MyActionSubmit",
        data: "{'viewModel':" + JSON.stringify(viewModel) + "}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            alert("Successfully sent ngpartdetails to controller.");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("Passing data to controller failed");
        }
    });
});
```

I expected that the `viewModel` data would be successfully passed to the controller, but when I debug it says that the viewModel contains null objects on my controller.

Comment: use this one: `public void MyActionSubmit([FromBody]saveViewModel viewModel)`

Comment: Have you checked your jquery code execute.. also check your button type like submit or button..

Comment: @hassan.ef Nope it did not work :(

Comment: change data to this one maybe its work:  data: { 'viewModel': JSON.stringify(viewModel)}

Comment: @A.M.Patel yes i have checked that my button type is of "submit"..the jquery code did not complain anything from my developer tools console

Comment: @hassan.ef nope it did not work:(

Comment: use this one in constructor of class `saveViewModel`: `public class saveViewModel
{ public saveViewModel(){ this.ngpartDetails = new List<NgpartDetails>(); this.GeneralDetails= new List<GeneralDetails>();} 
}`

Comment: set button type to button and then check your jquery button click is working. if not working than try to use different jquery click event.

Comment: @hassan.ef it will give an error on the ":" sign

Comment: @A.M.Patel i think u might be right that my jquery is not prorpely executed, after i had set my button type to 'button", the jquery successs or message alert did not respond.

Comment: @Jeff Fu where is ":"? I mean you should create new of your list object in constructor of  saveViewModel.